# What is the difference between java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode and org.asynchttpclient.util.Base64.decode?

Tags: java, base64, decode

I have a base64 encoded string,is encoded in php,now I have to decode to raw string in java.

At the first time, I try to decode by `java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString)`.

But it throws `Illegal base64 character 25`.

[image: error message pic]

After many attempts，I make it with `org.asynchttpclient.util.Base64.decode(encodedString)`

But, what's the difference ? thx so much!

Comment: Differences are probably available in the documentation, but I'd be more concerned about the illegal Base64 you're decoding.

Comment: It looks like you have invalid base64, `java.util` is telling you so, and `asynchttpclient` is papering over it to give you something even if it's invalid.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but with **asynchttpclient decode**, i can get what I need, although the decoded string is not perfect(something I can not see), The screenshot is ![screenshot](https://fudongdong-statics.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/autoupload/2022-04-25/ea40404b43be4f879ee36720e099f407.image.png)

Comment: "character 25"? Is that a percent sign?  (%)

Comment: @g00se I an not sure, Maybe "end of medium" ? https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp https://ascii.cl/

Comment: Ah yes. I was thinking of 0x25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation: [org.asynchttpclient.util.Base64](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.asynchttpclient/async-http-client/2.1.0-alpha25/org/asynchttpclient/util/Base64.html)

> Implements the "base64" binary encoding scheme as defined by [RFC 2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045).
> Portions of code here are taken from Apache Pivot

So it is the implementation of Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions (MIME) [RFC 2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045)

According to documentation: [java.util.Base64.getDecoder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)

> Returns a Base64.Decoder that decodes using the Basic type base64
> encoding scheme.
>
> Basic
>
> Uses "The Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 1 of [RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648) and [RFC 2045](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2045) for encoding and decoding operation. The encoder does not add any
> line feed (line separator) character. The decoder rejects data that
> contains characters outside the base64 alphabet.

`java.util.Base64.getDecoder()` returns decoder according to  [RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648). Decoder rejects data that contains characters outside the base64 alphabet. It is not MIME implementation.

To have the same behavior you need to use `java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder()`

> MIME
>
> Uses the "The Base64 Alphabet" as specified in Table 1 of RFC 2045 for
> encoding and decoding operation. The encoded output must be
> represented in lines of no more than 76 characters each and uses a
> carriage return '\r' followed immediately by a linefeed '\n' as the
> line separator. No line separator is added to the end of the encoded
> output. All line separators or other characters not found in the
> base64 alphabet table are ignored in decoding operation.

The MIME encoder generates a Base64-encoded output using the basic alphabet.
Each line of the output is no longer than 76 characters. Also, it ends with a carriage return followed by a linefeed (\r\n).

[What is the difference between base64 and MIME base 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201225/what-is-the-difference-between-base64-and-mime-base-64)